# Adding multiple UI Elements and Constrain Together

Tags: swift, autolayout, snapkit

I have a UIView setup like this

- UIView

  - UIScrollView (`self.scrollView`)

    - UIView (`self.contentView`)
    - LineChartView (`self.chart`)
    - M13CheckBox [subset of UIControl]

The chart display includes multiple lines, which I'm planning to control with multiple checkboxes. However, I can't seem to constrain the checkboxes to each other!

Here is my code:

```
    var unconstrainedChecks = [M13Checkbox]()
    for year in years { // years = ["2015","2016","2017"]
        let checkbox = CustomizedCheckBox().checkbox
        checkbox.backgroundColor = .purple
        self.contentView.addSubview(checkbox)
        unconstrainedChecks.append(checkbox)
    }
    for i in 0..<unconstrainedChecks.count - 1 {
        print(i)
        let checkbox = unconstrainedChecks[i]
        let nextCheckbox = unconstrainedChecks[i+1]
        checkbox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            if i == 0 {
                make.top.equalTo(self.chart.snp.bottom).offset(20)
                make.width.height.equalTo(50)
                make.left.equalTo(self.contentView)
            }
            make.bottom.equalTo(nextCheckbox.snp.top)
        }

        nextCheckbox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.height.equalTo(50)
            make.left.equalTo(self.contentView)
            make.top.equalTo(checkbox.snp.bottom)
        }

    }
```

Where `CustomizedCheckBox` is

```
class CustomizedCheckBox {
    let checkbox: M13Checkbox
    init() {
        checkbox = M13Checkbox()
        checkbox.setCheckState(.checked, animated: false)
        checkbox.stateChangeAnimation = .bounce(.fill)
        checkbox.secondaryTintColor =  UIColor(hexString: "47cae8")
        checkbox.secondaryCheckmarkTintColor = .white //checkmark
        checkbox.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "53cce7")
    }
}
```

I looked at the View Hierarchal Thing, and I couldn't see the checkbox at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I needed to constrain the last checkbox to `self.contentView.bottom`.

added this into the `nextCheckbox` loop.

```
            if i + 1 == unconstrainedChecks.count - 1 {
                make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.bottom)
            }
```